# Rmarkdown - inject r expression to inline markdown code

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to inject R expression into inline markdown code from a function?
Suppose we have a Rmarkdown document like this:

```
# doc.Rmd
...
This is my random number `r sample(1:10, 1)`.
```

Can it be transformed into this somehow?:

````
    ```
    insert_number <- function() {
      `r sample(1:10, 1)`   # the code is invalid, only illustration
    }
    ```

   This is my random number `r insert_number()`
````

My goal is to generate r inline chunks dynamically with a function and when the document is rendered those chunks are interpreted correctly as they were usual chunks. I don't want to insert a random number, I want to insert the expression `r sample(1:10, 1)` as it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found a solution looking a little more elegant to the one proposed by @user2554330. Here's my approach:

````
# .Rmd file

```{r}
insert_number <- function() {
  function() {
    rnorm(1)
  }
}
```

This is my number `r (insert_number())()`.
````